# Any way to specify different NA actions for different functions in summaryBy?

Tags: r, grouping

Is there a way to specify different NA actions for different functions in summaryBy? For example, say I want the mean and the number of observations for various groups in a data set. I can do this:

```
library(doBy)
var1 = c(10.5,15,6.2,3.5,NA,NA)
group = c("A","B","B","A","B","A")
df = data.frame(var1, group)
summaryBy(var1 ~ group, data=df, FUN=c(mean,length), na.rm=TRUE)
```

You need the `na.rm = TRUE` so that the `mean` function will work with missing values. However, the `length` function takes only one argument, yet `summaryBy` passes `na.rm=TRUE` to `length` as wells as to `mean`, so the `summaryBy` call gives the following error:

```
Error in currFUN(x, ...) : 
2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

Is there some way to specify within `summaryBy` that the `na.rm=TRUE` argument should be passed only to `mean` and not to `length`? Or is there some other (reasonably elegant) workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is to define a wrapper around `mean` with `na.rm=TRUE` as the default.

For example:

```
mean <- function(x)base::mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
summaryBy(var1 ~ group, data=df, FUN=c(mean,length))

  group var1.mean var1.length
1     A       7.0           3
2     B      10.6           3
```

And you can also pass an anonymous function:

```
rm(mean)
summaryBy(var1 ~ group, data=df, FUN=c(function(x)mean(x, na.rm=TRUE),length))

  group var1.FUN1 var1.FUN2
1     A       7.0         3
2     B      10.6         3
```